# Solving electrical circuit with two voltage sources

Tags: circuit-analysis

I want to participate with the physics olympiad. I encountered a question with usual electronics but two voltage sources (!?) and I had to calculate the voltage / currents / resistance values of that circuit. I cant copy the question over here, but I know for sure you can think of similar circumstances. At least, I see that the two voltage source work against each other (!?). Is that even possible?
BTW, as usual with questions in physics, this is idealized.

Here is the circuit

[image]

Question comes from [here - Question 9](http://www.fisme.uu.nl/nno/opgaven/bestanden/Ronde1-Theorie-2004.pdf)

Question translated from dutch to english:

In a circuit there are two power supplies with a voltage of 10V and 20V. The voltmeter gives the value 15V. How big is the value of the resistor R?

Please... I never encountered more than one voltage source in one circuit before

Comment: What is the question? "How do two voltage sources work against each other?" Can you post an example schematic? As written, your question is vague and unanswerable.

Comment: What you need to learn is the *superposition theorem*: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superposition_theorem

Comment: There is an important difference between ideal sources and practical sources like batteries or power supplies. Ideal voltage sources can be connected in series whichever way you want, but practical andy varying sources (batteries, PSU's) should may not cope well.

Answer (score 4):

OK since we are told the voltmeter measures 15V then the junction of the two resistors must be either -5V or +25V and the top of resistor "R" is 20+10 = 30V.

We can call the bottom node 0V as its tied to earth.  The junction of the two batteries is 10V and the top node is 20V above that i.e. 30V

Now we are told that the meter reads 15V so the junction of the two resistors must be either 10 - 15 = -5V or 10 + 15 = 25V.  And -5V makes no sense so it must be +25V as shown

[image]

We therefore have 25 volts across the 50 ohm resistor so there is 0.5 amps flowing through it.

The other resistor R has 30V - 25V = 5V across it so its value is:

5V / 0.5A = 10 ohms

---

When we talk about voltage we always mean a voltage difference; and when we say the voltage at a certain point is x what we really mean to say the voltage at a certain point with respect to another point is x.

So first step is to choose our reference point. This could be any node but since the bottom node is earthed I have chosen that as my 0V point.  If I had chosen a different point some of the voltages would have been negative. It's OK to have negative voltages however as we are only ever concerned about the difference between two points: This is why you sometimes hear the term "potential difference" instead of voltage.

From this bottom node (labelled 0V) there is a 10V battery so the top of the battery will be 10V more positive than the bottom node. Its voltage will be:

0V + 10V = 10V  so we can label this point 10V.

Now from this point there is a 20V battery so the top of this battery will be 20V more positive than the bottom which we have already established is 10V.  The voltage of the top node is therefore:

10V + 20V = 30V so we can label this point 30V.

On the right hand side of the circuit we have two series resistors and since the voltmeter (at least in the ideal world of your physics exam) takes no current the voltage at the point where the resistors meet must be more than 0V and less than 30V.

We are told the voltmeter measures 15V.  We are not told which way round the voltmeter is so the voltage at the junction of the two resistors could be either 15V higher than the 10V node or 15V lower That is

10V + 15V = 25V or 10V - 15V = -5V

Now we have already said that this node must be between 0V and 30V so The second answer does not make sense.  We can finally label this node 25V.

Because we are assuming an ideal voltmeter which takes no current the same current must flow in both resistors (and also both batteries).

We know the 50 ohm resistor has 25V one side of it and 0V the other making 25V across it so by ohms law we can calculate the current

I = V / R  = 25 volts / 50 ohms = 0.5 amps

Now for the resistor R we know we have 30V one side and 25V the other so there is 5V across it and we know the current has it has to be the same as the current in the other resistor

So using ohms law again we can work out the resistance.

R = V / I = 5 volt / 0.5 amp = 10 ohms

---

Another way of approaching this problem.

[image]

This time I have chosen the junction of the two batteries as my reference point

bottom (50 ohm) resistor has +15V one side and -10V the other

Voltage across it is thus

15V - (-10V) = 15V + 10V = 25V

Current is 25 volt / 50 ohm = 0.5 amp

Top resistor (R) has 15V one side and 20V the other

Voltage across it is thus

20V - 15V = 5V

Current is 0.5 amp as it must be the same as in the other resistor

Its resistance is therefore:

5 volt / 0.5 amp = 10 ohm

I trust all is clear now as I don't think I can simplify the analysis any further.

Comment: ho ho not so fast.... please explain me how you came to the conclusion that the top resistor has 30 V through it? And why -5 / 15 V of the junction? Which junction? Could you elaborate more please in your steps? I want to learn how you solve circuits with 2 voltage sources...

Comment: Can you elaborate more please? I dont get the how you simply decide sth is so much volts etc. How is the grounding 0 volts? Do you use superposition? How is the top 30 V? Doesnt superposition take away the fact that the junction is 25 V? How the hell do you think man?

Comment: OK, thanks so much for clearing the voltage part as potential difference and literally DIFFERENCE. I didnt really think about that and just took it for granted. However, since when does an ideal voltmeter not take any current? Because of that, I couldnt have predicted this. I know what you mean, but this ideal physics really makes even less sense than what I though was ideal. BTW, please tell do you use superposition (since you do 10 + 20 = 30 V on top in first explanation) or not? Its a lot clearer now, thanks a lot man.

Comment: In an ideal world it's assumed that the measuring equipment does not change what its measuring so for a voltmeter to be ideal it should take no current otherwise it would change the voltage being measured. In practice modern digital meters are several megohms so the effect would be small. I'm not using superposition theory here just [Kirchhoff's circuit laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws).  That is what current flows into a node must also flow out and the sum of the voltages for any path to two specific nodes must be the same.